# Recreating a URL string

Tags: javascript, angular.js, url

This is what my `viewObject` looks like:

```
{
    description: "GOOG AAPL TSLA"
    id: 42
    ticker_1: "GOOG"
    ticker_2: "AAPL"
    ticker_3: "TSLA"
    timespan: "1mo"
}
```

Here is the function use to check the object. In a very dirty fashion, it creates a string to be used to replace the URL with:

```
function createUrl(viewObj) {
    var urlString  = '',
        ticker1    = '',
        ticker2    = '',
        ticker3    = '',
        time       = '';

    if (viewObj.ticker_1) {
        ticker1 = '&ticker_1='+viewObj.ticker_1;
        ulrString = ulrString+ticker1;
    }
    if (viewObj.ticker_2) {
        ticker2 = '&ticker_2='+viewObj.ticker_2;
        ulrString = ulrString+ticker2;
    }
    if (viewObj.ticker_3) {
        ticker3 = '&ticker_3='+viewObj.ticker_3;
        ulrString = ulrString+ticker3;
    }

    if (viewObj.timespan) {
        time = '&timespan='+viewObj.timespan;
        ulrString = ulrString+time;
    }

    console.log('/dashboard'+ulrString);
    return '/dashboard'+ulrString;
}
```

I have multiple `if`/`else` statements and code that can be repeated. How would you accomplish this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316781/how-to-build-query-string-with-javascript ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, however that solution is definitely not what I want... hmm I will see if there is a lodash solution for this

Comment: Is this in a Node environment or in the browser?

Comment: Browser, this is a small function in my Angular app

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the params options in `$http` for this? `$http.get('/dashboard', { ticker_1: ticker_1 })` would resolve to `/dashboard?ticker_1=foo` if `ticker_1` is `foo` or just `/dashboard` otherwise. It's also a service - `$httpParamsSerializer`

Comment: Oh interesting, didn't know `$http` did that.. well I don't want a refresh to happen actually. I just want the URL to update, based on clicks, then when a refresh happens, what I do is rebuild the UI based on the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function createUrl(viewObj) {
    var urlParams = ['ticker_1', 'ticker_2', 'ticker_3', 'timespan'],
        urlString = '',
        current;
    for (var i = 0; i < urlParams.length; i++) {
        current = urlParams[i];
        if (viewObj[current]) urlString += '&' + current + '=' + viewObj[current];
    }
    console.log('/dashboard' + urlString);
    return '/dashboard' + urlString;
}
```

**The algorithm explained:**

As the treatment you need for each of the URL parameters is the same, it's enough with storing all of them in an array (`urlParams`) and then iterating over each that array.

At each iteration, `current` will be one of them. E.g.: at the first iteration, `current` will be 'ticker_1'. That way,

```
if (viewObj[current])
```

replaces

```
if (viewObj.ticker_1)
```

Besides, it's not necessary to store the new string to a variable (as you do with `ticker1`, `ticker2`, etc.), before appending it to `urlString`, so I just removed those lines.

Finally, for string concatenation, the `+=` operator can be used, so

```
urlString = urlString + something;
```

can be replaced with

```
urlString += something;
```

Comment: Thanks! I love how clean and simple this is, I get it too... I know what `params` to look for, I set `current` to the next `param` it finds, if it finds it add it to the string. The loop does however has to run for each possible param, I wonder if there is a way to optimize that? Maybe a `_.find` or something with lodash?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean write code that would repeat the multiple `if/else` statements? cause that would be the right idea and make your code more DRY.

The first thing to take a look at is your data structure. As it is, you have hard-coded a handful of ticker properties that would make iteration difficult. You could use a `for/in` loop to go through the properties of your object, but we know we don't want the `description` or `id` in the string. Better to put all tickers in an array. That way it'll be easy to create a string with as many (or little) tickers as you want.

```
{
    description: "GOOG AAPL TSLA"
    id: 42
    tickers: ["GOOG", "AAPL", "TSLA"]
    timespan: "1mo"
}
```

It's now easy to iterate over the tickers and construct a string out of them. Since we always start with `ticker_<n>` as the beginning, we can construct that inside our loop, using the index to count which ticker # we are on.

For the function:

```
function createUrl(viewObject){
    // use .map to add "ticker_<n>=<value>" to each of the tickers,
    // then join with "&" for the query.
    var urlString = viewObject.tickers
        .map(function(ticker, index){
             // prepend the first query with its own '&'
            var and = index === 0 ? "&" : "";

            //create a 1-indexed count of the tickers.
            var tickerNum = index + 1; 
            return and + "ticker_" + tickerNum + "=" + ticker;
        })
        .join('&'); //<--separate each query with "&"

    // for timespan, you don't need to make a seperate `time` variable,
    // this can be done in one line.
    if(viewObject.timespan) urlString += "&timespan=" + viewObject.timespan;

    console.log('/dashboard'+urlString);
    return '/dashboard'+urlString;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.